# How Can Hide Define Category in Post Contents?

Tags: categories, list

This is My Category List :

1- Years
2- Genere

And I use This Code For show in posts :

```
<?php the_category(' , ') ?>
```

How Can Hide "Year or Genere" in up code?

Please Help Me.i want Show Only One Category.

Comment: You can use [get_the_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_categories/) filter and unset certain categories that you want. Just remember to remove the filter after `the_category`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `get_the_categories` filter before `the_category(' , ')` then remove it. So it will not effect categories on other places.

```
add_filter( 'get_the_categories', 'remove_selected_categories' );
the_category(' , ');
remove_filter( 'get_the_categories', 'remove_selected_categories' );
```

In callback function check for categories to remove then remove them!

```
function remove_selected_categories( $categories ) {

    $categories_to_remove = array(
        'years',
        'genere'
    ); //Place the slug for categories

    foreach ($categories as $index => $single_cat) {

        if (in_array($single_cat->slug, $categories_to_remove)) {
            unset($categories[$index]);
        }
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

Check the documentation for [get_the_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_categories/) filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ):
$separator = ' ';
$skipped_cat = 'Genere'; 
    foreach( $categories as $category ):
        if( $category->name != $skipped_cat ):
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: I could not do.

Where should I copy this code?

Comment: It depends on where do you need to run this code, is it on a single post? or a loop where it shows multiple ppsts?, ..etc. Please provide more details to answer this question.

Comment: in single.php after the <?php if ( have_posts() ) :
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>